# BasicAuthProvider in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, url, basic-authentication, servicestack

I've got an issue with the BasicAuthProvider in ServiceStack. POST-ing to the  CredentialsAuthProvider (/auth/credentials) is working fine.

The problem is that when GET-ing (in Chrome):
`http://foo:pwd@localhost:81/tag/string/list`

the following is the result

> Handler for Request not found:
>
> Request.HttpMethod: GET
>   Request.HttpMethod: GET
>   Request.PathInfo: /login
>   Request.QueryString: System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
>   Request.RawUrl: /login?redirect=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a81%2ftag%2fstring%2flist

which tells me that it redirected me to /login instead of serving the /tag/... request.

Here's the entire code for my AppHost:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase, IMessageSubscriber
{
    private ITagProvider myTagProvider;
    private IMessageSender mySender;

    private const string UserName = "foo";
    private const string Password = "pwd";

    public AppHost( TagConfig config, IMessageSender sender )
        : base( "BM App Host", typeof( AppHost ).Assembly )
    {
        myTagProvider = new TagProvider( config );
        mySender = sender;
    }

    public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
    {
        public override void OnAuthenticated( IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> authInfo )
        {
            authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().SaveSession( session );
        }
    }

    public override void Configure( Funq.Container container )
    {
        Plugins.Add( new MetadataFeature() );

        container.Register<BeyondMeasure.WebAPI.Services.Tags.ITagProvider>( myTagProvider );
        container.Register<IMessageSender>( mySender );

        Plugins.Add( new AuthFeature( () => new CustomUserSession(),
                new AuthProvider[] {
                    new CredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
                    new BasicAuthProvider(), //Sign-in with Basic Auth
                } ) );

        container.Register<ICacheClient>( new MemoryCacheClient() );
        var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>( userRep );

        string hash;
        string salt;
        new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString( Password, out hash, out salt );
        // Create test user
        userRep.CreateUserAuth( new UserAuth
        {
            Id = 1,
            DisplayName = "DisplayName",
            Email = "as@if.com",
            UserName = UserName,
            FirstName = "FirstName",
            LastName = "LastName",
            PasswordHash = hash,
            Salt = salt,
        }, Password );
    }
}
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong with either the SS configuration or how I am calling the service, i.e. why does it not accept the supplied user/pwd?

**Update1**: Request/Response captured in Fiddler2when only BasicAuthProvider is used.
No Auth header sent in the request, but also no Auth header in the response.

```
GET /tag/string/AAA HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:81
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)        Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ss-pid=Hu2zuD/T8USgvC8FinMC9Q==; X-UAId=1; ss-id=1HTqSQI9IUqRAGxM8vKlPA==

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /login?redirect=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a81%2ftag%2fstring%2fAAA
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3,926 Win32NT/.NET
Date: Sat, 10 Nov 2012 22:41:51 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

**Update2** Request/Response with HtmlRedirect = null . SS now answers with the Auth header, which Chrome then issues a second request for and authentication succeeds

```
GET http://localhost:81/tag/string/Abc HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:81
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ss-pid=Hu2zuD/T8USgvC8FinMC9Q==; X-UAId=1; ss-id=1HTqSQI9IUqRAGxM8vKlPA==

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3,926 Win32NT/.NET
WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="/auth/basic"
Date: Sat, 10 Nov 2012 22:49:19 GMT

0

GET http://localhost:81/tag/string/Abc HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:81
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic Zm9vOnB3ZA==
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ss-pid=Hu2zuD/T8USgvC8FinMC9Q==; X-UAId=1; ss-id=1HTqSQI9IUqRAGxM8vKlPA==
```

Comment: Can you show the requests that are being made by the browser? You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) for that.

Comment: As mythz writes below, there is not Auth header beeing sent, as SS doesn't respond with the 401 Www-Authenticate: Basic since I've got two AuthProviders registered. Also see my question to mythz below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixing `foo:pwd@` to a url like:

```
http://foo:pwd@localhost:81/tag/string/list
```

is not how you do BasicAuth with HTTP, the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for an example:

#### Sending BasicAuth request with a HTTP client

When the user agent wants to send the server authentication credentials it may use the Authorization header.

The Authorization header is constructed as follows:

1. Username and password are combined into a string **"username:password"**
2. The resulting string literal is then encoded using **Base64**
3. The **Authorization** method and a space i.e. **"Basic "** is then put before the encoded string.

For example, if the user agent uses **'Aladin'** as the username and **'sesam open'** as the password then the header is formed as follows:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGluOnNlc2FtIG9wZW4=
```

Comment: The `http://username:password@host/` notation is resolved by the browser (Chrome at least, [IE stopped](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms04-004) doing that). If the addressed site at first sends a 401 response with a `Www-Authenticate: Basic` header, the browser re-issues the request using the supplied username and password in a `Authorization: Basic` header.

Comment: I tried `http://username:password@host/` in Chrome and it didn't convert the url into a Basic Auth header, it just sent the request right through. ServiceStack only sends `401 Www-Authenticate: Basic` if BasicAuth is the only AuthProvider registered.

Comment: If I enter http://foo:bar@stackoverflow.com/, Chrome 23.0.1271.64 m sends me to http://stackoverflow.com without sending the credentials. It works for me as I described above, locally on a new site (i.e. the browser doesn't have a password remembered for it) that requires basic authentication.

Comment: @mythz So removing the CredentialsAuthProvider should make this work (if using Chrome), is that what you're saying? I tried it, but according to Fiddler2 SS still responds with the redirection?

Comment: Can you post the http request + response traffic? You can use something's like fiddler or web inspector.

Comment: Also to avoid the redirect (i.e. when calling from a browser/HTML client) you can set **HtmlRedirect** to null, e.g: `new AuthFeature(...) { HtmlRedirect = null };`

Comment: Setting HtmlRedirect = null seems to have done the trick, as can be seen in the edited question above. However, how can you then redirect unauthorized users to a login page?

Comment: You can't do both, either you challenge for Authentication with a `401` or you redirect to a login page with a `301` or `302`. You can use the **HtmlRedirect** globally on the `AuthFeature` or locally adhoc on the `[Autenticate]` attribute to specify the url on which to redirect to.